# Can't acquire lock when trying to synchronize discord.py commands

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am writing my discord bot, which has a few commands. However, recently need appeared for every command to check a list before executing. So, naturally the right move is to synchronize the commands, with something like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import logging
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>>', case_insensitive=True)
token = 'lul'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
lock = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, members : commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
    await ctx.send(len(members))
    await ctx.send('approaching critical section')
    with await lock:
        await ctx.send('in critical section')
        time.sleep(10)
    await ctx.send('exited critical section')
```

So, if you were to invoke the command with `>>test @abs @asda` you would expect to receive the output:

```
2
approaching critical section
in critical section
exited critical section
```

But instead what we get is this:

```
2
approaching critical section
```

So, this means that the coroutine doesn't fall into the critical section. It could be that the coroutine crashes silently or times out for being unable to acquire a lock (if that's how it works actually).

Nevertheless help on solving this problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [`async with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-with) instead of `with await`.  You should also create the lock in the global namespace, and use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>>', case_insensitive=True)
lock = asyncio.Lock()  # Doesn't require event loop

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, members : commands.Greedy[discord.Member]):
    await ctx.send(len(members))
    await ctx.send('approaching critical section')
    async with lock:
        await ctx.send('in critical section')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await ctx.send('exited critical section')
```